# Split dataframe's array column into multiple columns in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to spark. I have an array column and want to cut it into multiple columns. How should I operate?
Looking forward to your answers.

```
Input:
+-------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
|name   |subjects                                                         |
+-------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
|Michael|[{"subject": "english", score:100},{"subject": "math", score:80}]|
|John   |[{"subject": "english", score:75},{"subject": "math", score:66}] |
+-------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+

Output:
+-------+-------+----+
|name   |english|math|
+-------+-------+----+
|Michael|100    |80  |
|John   |75     |66  |
+-------+-------+----+
```

Comment: Can you show the schema of the table, how does it handle map that contains both ints and strings as value?

Comment: Judging  by formatting - `subjects` isn't array of map, then what is it? Array of what?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a guarantee that all the values in subjects column have same "keys", that is subjects? In a general case, you can't turn array value into columns since arrays in different rows can have different (and big) number of elements. If you do know that in all rows subjects field is of the same length and the order is similar you can do it manually

```
df.withColumn("english", element_at(element_at(col("subjects"),1),"score").
   withColumn("math",
```

etc

If you are not sure about the order, you can sort the array, although I am not sure how does array of maps sort. You can use UDF to extract scores, in that case it won't depend on the order.

If you don't know the subjects in advance you can first collect all the subject names and then generate the necessary code that adds columns.

Another way to take care of the order of entries in the array is to transform the array of maps int a map where subject are the keys. Easy with udf, but can be done with spark functions with two `explode`s and then `groupBy` and `map_from_entries` or `map_from_arrays`. You will still have to convert the map entries into columns using sequence of `withColumn`

Actually, it seems you can transform the array of maps into a map using `transform` to replace maps by structs and then `map_from_entries` to turn it into a map. No need for either `udf` or `explode`. Like this

```
val df1 = df.withColumn("subjects_map",map_from_entries(
  transform(col("subjects"), 
     m => struct(element_at(m, "subject"), element_at(m, "score")))))
```

Which creates the following table

```
+-------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------+
|name   |subject                                                             |map                         |
+-------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------+
|Michael|[{subject -> english, score -> 100}, {subject -> math, score -> 90}]|{english -> 100, math -> 90}|
|John   |[{subject -> english, score -> 60}, {subject -> math, score -> 50}] |{english -> 60, math -> 50} |
+-------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------+
```

If the array is array of json-encoded strings instead of maps then the code changes as follows

```
val df1 = df.withColumn("subjects_map",map_from_entries(
  transform(col("subjects"), 
     m => struct(get_json_object(m, "$.subject"), get_json_object(m, "$.score")))))
```

And finally, the code that creates the columns

```
val subjs = df1.select(explode(map_keys(col("subjects_map"))) as "subj").
              distinct.as[String].collect // gather all the subj values

subjs.foldLeft(df1){ case (df, c) => 
    df.withColumn(c, element_at(col("subjects_map"), c)) } // add column for each one
```